# Make a specific program see the file-system differently on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems, symbolic-link, sandbox

I'm using Winamp since god knows when. I have all my songs in the media library with all my mp3 files with all kind of cool statistics like how many times I've listened to each song, ratings etc.

The situation began when I've moved to a new computer and copied all of Winamp's DB files. It worked great, except that my files are no longer on drive D:, but on drive E:.
Of course, I can create symbolic links, but I don't want to create 2 drive letters for the same HD.

**TL;DR;**

Is there a way to make a **specific** program to see the HDD differently?
e.g., think that files exist in one path, although they are in a different path.

**NOTICE: I'm not looking for a solution for my Winamp situation, rather a general solution.**

Comment: I don't know of any such, but one possibility might be to sandbox the desired program (Winamp or wherever) and to make the symbolic link in the sandbox (or use a virtual machine, just for the program). That sounds like a bit of effort, so only you can judge if it is worth it to you.

Comment: I know that you asked for a general solution, but if you find that you have to accept a Winamp specific solution then hopefully you can just do a global edit on the log files - or is the data in a  database? If so, which?

Comment: For my winamp situation, I created another HDD letter for the same drive. But that's  an ugly solution (I now have an extra drive letter). Winamp uses a DB file, and I can't edit it. Anyway, Winamp is just an example.

Comment: Similarly to @Mawg's comment: Winamp surely stores all the file data in a flat file or a database of some sort. Could you not look at this file and see if you can update the locations for your new drive letter?

Comment: I can do all sorts of things with Winamp, but as I stated, I'm interested in a general solution that will work with any program.

Comment: Editing the file/database to point to the new drive sounds like one solution though if you have to rename 50,000 songs find and replace would be ideal.  They may have encrypted the db in a really easy algorithm possibly?

Comment: I'm looking for a general solution for any program - not for Winamp only.

Comment: Simple solution - re-assign drive `E:` as drive `D:`, first removing the mountpoint for `D:` in Disk Management [`DiskMgmt.msc`] or `DiskPart`, reassign `E:` to `D:`, then go back to either program and reassign the old `D:` drive to `E:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a windows program see a different view of the hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1331901/how-to-make-a-windows-program-see-a-different-view-of-the-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using application shims with Microsoft's Application Compatibility Toolkit, you can achieve app-specific file-system view.

The technique is described in [this StackOverflow page](https://superuser.com/questions/1331901/how-to-make-a-windows-program-see-a-different-view-of-the-hard-drive)